# Control Point Registration using matlab -'fitgeotrans' function

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and I'm trying to do a Control Point Registration using their guide:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/point-mapping.html

It works fine until the 'fitgeotrans' function where I get an error that saying:
'Undefined function or variable 'input_points'.

I read the Matlab help and the previous "cpselect"  function gives me two nX2 arrays with the coordinates which are saved (by the 'cpselect' function) in two array variables 'input_points' and 'base_points'. So, I really don't understand why the next function can't "See" them and considers them 'Undefined'.

My code is attached bellow. Thank you for your help.

```
function [Y] =EBL

ReferenceImg=imread('GFI.jpg');                          %This is the fixed image
CroppedImg=imcrop(ReferenceImg);                         %Crop the image
close                                                    %close the imcrop window
ResizedIReferenceImg= imresize(CroppedImg,[1000 1000]);  %re-size the fixed image

t=imagesc(ResizedIReferenceImg);                         %Set transparency of fixed image
set(t,'AlphaData',0.5);
hold on

I = imread('GF.bmp');                                    %This is the moving picture
MovingImg = imrotate(I,-5,'nearest','crop');             % Rotate the moving picture cw 

ResizedMovingImg= imresize(MovingImg,[1000 1000]);       %re-size the moving image
h=imagesc(ResizedMovingImg);                             %Set transparency of moving image
set(h,'AlphaData',0.6);
close

cpselect(ResizedMovingImg,ResizedIReferenceImg);         %Alignment
tform = fitgeotrans(input_points,base_points,'NonreflectiveSimilarity');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MATLAB doesn't, by default, wait for you to be done before moving on from `cpselect`. So it simply moves on from `cpselect` to `tform` before you have a chance to actually select any points, at which point `input_points` doesn't yet exist. You have to set the `Wait` parameter, and doing so also affects the outputs.  With `Wait` on, call `cpselect` something like this:

```
[input_points,base_points] = cpselect(MovingImg,ReferenceImg,'Wait', true);
```

When calling `cpselect` in this way, you will not have the "Export Points to Workspace" option. Instead, the selected points will be output into the variables `input_points,base_points` when the `cpselect` window is closed.